# Would we be able to do haram things in jannah?

Tags: jannah, sin

I wanted to know if it would be OK to do haram in heaven (e.g. drink alcohol) because you have followed all the rules that Allah has given you and gotten to paradise so now you can do whatever you want and have whatever you want right? And would there be any electronics in heaven?

Comment: In jannah the drinks all are permitted because everything is purified. "They shall pass therein from one to another a cup wherein there shall be nothing vain nor any sin." (52:23) also see (56:28)

Answer (score 1):

There's alcohol in Paradise, but that alcohol will not make you drunk like the one we have in this world.

And for Haram things, in Jannah, you won't ask for something which is illogical. Our thoughts are purified. Now you may think that you want to do Haram things, but in Jannah you won't be wishing for them as it's not possible as our thoughts are purified. We will wish for good things, and they will be granted. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
              In the name of Allah, the most compassionate, the most merciful
```

Briefly speaking, to the best of my knowledge, the answer of your query relatively would be yeah. Actually it is narrated that the haram (forbidden) things/practices such as drinking (alcohol, weer,...) would be permissible for people who are in the paradise. Even it is said that although gold is haram for men in this world (to wear it), but it will be permissible for men then. Or as more accurate of the mentioned of the hadith (tradition), it is narrated that gold is considered as the adornment of women in this world, and that would be considered as the adornment of men in the heaven.

---

**Reference:**

[www.ghadeer.org](http://www.ghadeer.org/Book/71/11899)

[http://www.jamnews.ir](http://www.jamnews.ir/detail/News/427293)