# Can we commit sins in Jannah?

Tags: jannah, sin

Let's look at a homosexual. Say he's a practicing Muslim and for the sake of Allah he holds back his urges and desires all his life and Allah (SWT) rewards him with Jannah.

When he gets to Jannah, will he be able to execute his homosexual desires (it being a sin)? 
This is just an example. The question isn't primarily about homosexuality, but sins as a whole. **Can we commit sins in Jannah?**

Comment: Related post: [Would we be able to do haram things in jannah](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/28236/would-we-be-able-to-do-haram-things-in-jannah)

Answer (score 2):

assalam 3alaikom wa Rahmat Allah.
allah says: "(يَتَنَازَعُونَ فِيهَا كَأْسًا لَا لَغْوٌ فِيهَا وَلَا تَأْثِيمٌ) الطور/23 ."
means: There they shall pass from hand to hand a (wine) cup, free from any Laghw (dirty, false, evil vague talk between them), and free from sin (because it will be legal for them to drink).

The people of Paradise are cleansed of bad morals, despicable desires, and despicable purposes

God has enriched the believers and believers in Paradise thanks to the constant, and the abundance of the abundance, in which he allowed them the good bliss of the request of such sins.