# Will pork be allowed in Jannah?

Tags: halal-haram, jannah

Jannah is said to have rivers of wine, gold clothes and beautiful music. If those are allowed in heaven, does it mean we can also eat pork and draw living things? Will it also be okay to listen rock, hiphop or any other genre of music?

Comment: Read this question/answer. It will help you understand. https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/28236/would-we-be-able-to-do-haram-things-in-jannah